# JavaFX not loading GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, tableview

When I run my code in Eclipse the java window opens but there is no GUI from JavaFX. I have checked the console in Eclipse and there are no errors there.

I have even gone as far as to rewrite the project in a different directory but I get the same result.

How can I fix this?

Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;


public class Main extends Application {
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      try {
        FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root1,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

MainController.java

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

@FXML private TableView<Product> table;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> Code;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> Brand;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> Type;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> Colour;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> Size;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, Integer> Quantity;


public ObservableList<Product> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Product ("GD05", "Gildan", "T-Shirt", "Black", "Medium", 10),
        new Product ("GD05", "Gildan", "T-Shirt", "Black", "Large", 5),
        new Product ("GD05", "Gildan", "T-Shirt", "Black", "X Large", 3),
        new Product ("GD05", "Gildan", "T-Shirt", "Black", "XX Large", 1)
        );


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    Code.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("Code"));
    Brand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("Brand"));
    Type.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("Type"));
    Colour.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("Colour"));
    Size.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("Size"));
    Quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("Quantity"));
    table.setItems(list);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is loading the GUI: it's just not displaying it, because you don't ask it to.

```
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      try {

        // loads the FXML, but discards the result:
        FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));

        // creates a new, empty BorderPane
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();

        // makes the empty border pane the root of the scene:
        Scene scene = new Scene(root1,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        // sets the scene in the stage and shows it:
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

You need something like:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root1,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
   } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

This assumes the root element of your FXML file is a `BorderPane`, which I'm guessing is the intention here. If not, you can either change `BorderPane` to the relevant type, or you can do

```
BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
root1.setCenter(FXMLLoader.load(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the below has to be put in 
 a container.

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
```

Like

```
BorderPane root1;
root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
```